# Boost Rcpp (BH package) Multi precision

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I'm trying to learn how to use the boost multi precision package with Rcpp. My main problem seems to be with wrapping and returning. If any would could comment on the below code it could be appreciated.

The error I get is "cannot convert const boost::multiprecision::number

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp> 

using boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100;


// [[Rcpp::export]]

SEXP getBig(int a, int b) {

cpp_dec_float_100 seventh  = cpp_dec_float_100(1) / 7;

return Rcpp::wrap(seventh);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to call `Rcpp::wrap(someObject)`, we need *someone* to write the actual implementations of `wrap()` for the type of `someObject`.  Rcpp supplies this for many types, and add-on packages can do so too as we explain on in the ["Extending Rcpp" vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf).

Here it would be *your job* to either create such wrappers for `cpp_dec_float_100`, or to convert from that type to a type known by Rcpp.